# How to recognise gestures on pop-up view without interrupting gesture recognition on the view underneath?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom semi-transparent view with a custom gesture recogniser which recognises a single-finger gesture. It pops up over a full-screen view. The user interacts with the full-screen view using pinch and rotate gestures.

So what I'm trying to achieve is to prevent the pop-up view from interfering with the user's ability to continue pinching and rotating the full-screen view, even within the pop-up view's bounds. The pop-up view only needs to respond to my custom single-finger gesture recogniser.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.allTouches.count > 1) {
        return NO;
    }

    ...
}
```

I thought the above code might have cracked it, but sadly touches aren't populated when `pointInside` is called. Any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days' work I found a very simple answer. I hope it helps someone. In the initialisation of the pop-up view, simply add the gesture recogniser to the superview, or any full-screen view, rather than the pop-up's own view. The target can still be the pop-up view:

```
    self.recognizer = [[MyGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [fullscreenView addGestureRecognizer:self.recognizer];
```

And then disable user interaction:

```
    self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

This doesn't affect the gesture on the pop-up view, and the gestures associated with views underneath the pop-up now work fine too. If they compete with each other then the overrides in lorenzoliveto's answer can sort that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need the [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:) protocol. In particular those methods:

```
- gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:

- gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:
- gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:
```

Comment: I've tried always returning `NO` on the custom gesture recogniser's `shouldReceiveTouch`. This stops the recogniser from activating of course, but touches within the pop-up view still don't reach the gesture recognisers of the full-screen view underneath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below methods

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

I have used touchesBegan where i got the no of touches and based on the condition you can do whatever you want to do.

Below is the sample code

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
//Varible used for counting touches
        int nFingers += [touches count];
        //finger points
        for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
            if (nFingers < 1){
                CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
            }
        }
    }
```